# How to debug javascript in asp .net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I am using Visual Web Developer 2008.I have debug my javascript at localhost by adding a breakpoint/debugger in js file.It works perfectly in IE8 before.

This nice debug function is broken, after I try a developer tools(Press F12 in IE8).

Comment: I found that javascript is disabled in my IE8. After I endable it, everything work fine again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebug is my best tool for this.

I am talking of course for the [firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)

Answer (score 2):

Firebug is great (+1). However, the debugger in IE8 also works fine. I never use the VS debugger. If you're already using IE8 developer tools, just debug there instead of in VWD.